# Can controls be added to TableRow dynamically in android?

Tags: android, tablelayout

I tried adding buttons dynamically to TableRow, but ran into errors.

Layout xml

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:id="@+id/layout" >
<TableRow android:id="@+id/jumble">
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Error line

```
TableRow tr = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.jumble);
```

Got a null exception.

Is it even possible to do this? Or I will have to dynamically add TableRow to the TableLayout?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to find the parent ViewGroup first, and then get the child view from it.

```
TableLayout layout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
TableRow row = layout.findViewById(R.id.jumble);
// add buttons to the row
```

This is assuming you have set the TableLayout as the main layout for the activity in its onCreate method.

```
setContentView(R.layout.layout);
```